# Most Efficient / Fastest Way to Calculate a Matrix Quadratic Form in Julia (Symmetric Matrix)

Tags: performance, optimization, julia, linear-algebra

Given a symmetric matrix `mP`, what would be the fastest way to calculate the matrix quadratic form `vX' * mP * vX`?

Will it give extra performance if `mP` is positive definite?

Please address both the dense and the sparse case.

Comment: Cross-post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/most-efficient-way-to-compute-a-quadratic-matrix-form/66606

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70645845.