# How can I efficiently calculate a quadratic form in Julia?

Tags: performance, julia, quadratic-programming

I would like to calculate a quadratic form: `x' Q y` in Julia.
What would be the most efficient way to calculate this for the cases:

1. No assumption.
2. `Q` is symmetric.
3. `x` and `y` are the same (`x = y`).
4. Both `Q` is symmetric and `x = y`.

I know Julia has `dot()`. But I wonder if it is faster than BLAS call.

Comment: If you want to know more about quadratic forms in Julia : https://forem.julialang.org/vinodv/exploring-quadratic-forms-with-julia-k6e

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Julia's LinearAlgebra stdlib has native implementations of 3-argument `dot`, and also a version that is specialized for symmetric/hermitian matrices. You can view the source [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/017a3af018c6a7418510f0ad42ff0d409d01c838/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/generic.jl#L951) and [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/017a3af018c6a7418510f0ad42ff0d409d01c838/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/symmetric.jl#L578).

You can confirm that they do not allocate using `BenchmarkTools.@btime` or `BenchmarkTools.@ballocated` (remember to interpolate variables using `$`). The symmetry of the matrix is exploited, but looking at the source, I don't see how `x == y` could enable any serious speedup, except perhaps saving a few array lookups.

**Edit:** To compare the execution speed of the BLAS version and the native one, you can do

```
1.7.0> using BenchmarkTools, LinearAlgebra

1.7.0> X = rand(100,100); y=rand(100);

1.7.0> @btime $y' * $X * $y
  42.800 μs (1 allocation: 896 bytes)
1213.5489200642382

1.7.0> @btime dot($y, $X, $y)
  1.540 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1213.548920064238
```

This is a big win for the native version. For bigger matrices, the picture changes, though:

```
1.7.0> X = rand(10000,10000); y=rand(10000);

1.7.0> @btime $y' * $X * $y
  33.790 ms (2 allocations: 78.17 KiB)
1.2507105095988091e7

1.7.0> @btime dot($y, $X, $y)
  44.849 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1.2507105095988117e7
```

Possibly because BLAS uses threads, while `dot` is not multithreaded. There are also some floating point differences.

Comment: Could you check a version of `@dot` with `@tturbo` instead of `@simd`? I'd be interested in seeing how well `LoopVectorization` does here.

Comment: Just replacing `@simd` with `@turbo` produces a slight speedup, while `@tturbo` seems identical with `@turbo`. The macros are placed on the inner loop, though. I presume that threading the outer loop would be more beneficial.

Comment: Removing the `iszero` check (to allow `@tturbo` to work on the outer loop) gives me a result that is as fast as BLAS for big sizes, and 3x faster than `dot` for small sizes.

Comment: @OscarSmith, Care to share the exact code you used?

Answer (score 18):

The existing answers are both good. However, a few additional points:

- While Julia will indeed by default simply call BLAS here, as Oscar notes, some BLASes are faster than others. In particular, MKL will often be somewhat faster than OpenBLAS on modern x86 hardware. Fortunately, in Julia it is unusually easy to manually choose your BLAS backend. Simply typing `using MKL` at the REPL on Julia 1.7 or later will switch you to the MKL backend via the [MKL.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/MKL.jl) package.
- While it is not used by default, there do now exist a couple pure Julia linear algebra packages that can match or even beat traditional Fortran-based BLAS. In particular, [Octavian.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Octavian.jl):

[image: Octavian.jl benchmarks]

Comment: The point of the question was to have a direct method to calculate the scalar which would be faster than a BLAS call.

Comment: Ah, that seems to have been already answered by Bogumil's comments about `dot`, the comments about BLASes are relevant to the case of general linear algebra, which will occur for `y'*X*y`, and looking at the source, for _some_ of the steps in calls to three-arg `dot` except in the case of `dot(x::AbstractVector, A::AbstractMatrix, y::AbstractVector)` which has a non-allocating pure Julia implementation in Julia 1.4 and onwards.

Answer (score 10):

If your matrix is symmetric use the `Symmetric` wrapper to improve performance (a different method is called then):

```
julia> a = rand(10000); b = rand(10000);

julia> x = rand(10000, 10000); x = (x + x') / 2;

julia> y = Symmetric(x);

julia> @btime dot($a, $x, $b);
  47.000 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime dot($a, $y, $b);
  27.392 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

If `x` is the same as `y` see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/most-efficient-way-to-compute-a-quadratic-matrix-form/66606 for a discussion of options (but in general it seems `dot` is still fast then).

Comment: Indeed it will be more optimized than a general call to BLAS. But is there an implementation to directly compute the scalar?

Comment: `dot` produces a scalar.

Comment: But not directly. It first computes a temporary vector since it calls to BLAS as said by @OscarSmith.

Comment: @Eric Johnson Nope, unlike `y'*X*y`, `dot(y,X,y)` appears to not allocate at all. You can check this with `BenchmarkTools.@btime`.

Comment: @DNF, Are you aware of a BLAS function to handle the above? I thought using BLAS means it will do `Matrix x Vector` and then an inner product operation.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of that, but this is not using BLAS anyway, it appears to be fully Julia native.

Comment: Then @OscarSmith's answer is wrong?

Comment: @DNF, I think you should post this information as an answer for me to mark.

Comment: @OscarSmith normally has deeper knowledge than I about the codebase, so I am a bit hesitant, but `@less dot(a, X, b)` shows a native implementation, and `@btime` shows zero allocations. I will look into it a bit more, then post an answer.

Comment: I probably should have taken my advice and looked at the source before saying what the implementation was. Sorry for the misinformation :)

Comment: The fact that `dot` is not allocating was exactly the point of my answer above where I have shown `@btime` results.

Answer (score 7):

You can write an optimized loop using [Tullio.jl](https://github.com/mcabbott/Tullio.jl), doing this all in one sweep.  But I think it's not going to beat BLAS significantly:

> Chained multiplication is also very slow, because it doesn't know there's a better algorithm.

```
julia> # a, b, x are the same as in Bogumił's answer

julia> @btime dot($a, $x, $b);
  82.305 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> f(a, x, b) = @tullio r := a[i] * x[i,j] * b[j]
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime f($a, $x, $b);
  80.430 ms (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
```

Adding LoopVectorization.jl may be worth it:

```
julia> using LoopVectorization

julia> f3(a, x, b) = @tullio r := a[i] * x[i,j] * b[j]
f3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime f3($a, $x, $b);
  73.239 ms (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
```

But I don't know about how to go about the symmetric case.

```
julia> @btime dot($a, $(Symmetric(x)), $b);
  42.896 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

although there might be linear algebra tricks to cut that down intelligently with Tullio.jl.

In this kind of problem, benchmarking trade-offs is everything.

Comment: This is really great. Maybe supporting symmetric matrices should be a feature added to `Tulio.jl`.

Comment: IIUC, Tullio always devectorized to nested loops, so this wouldn't really make sense. What you could do is formulate the optimized implementation of whatever `Symmetric` will do as an einsum expression and use Tullio then.